# Test Class not Retrieving What's Expected

Tags: apex, unit-test

In my controller I have a `List`:

```
public List<ts2__Job__c> uaVacancies {
  get;
  set;
}
```

And a simple function to query:

```
public PageReference getUAVacancies() {
  uaVacancies = [SELECT Id, Name, ts2__Account__c, ts2__Contact__c, ts2__Priority__c, ts2__Stage__c, ts2__Job_Number__c, CreatedDate FROM ts2__Job__c WHERE (ts2__Recruiter__c = :user OR Development_Owner__c = :user) AND ts2__Status__c = 'Open'];

  return null;
}
```

In my test class' `@testSetup` I'm creating a `ts2__Job___c` object, then I have a method that calls the function `getUAVacancies()`.

It all covers fine, but I wanted to assert that the list is populated with 1 record. So when I do:

```
System.assertEquals(1, uaVacancies.size());
```

The test fails saying I'm expecting 1, but getting 0.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here! But here's my full test method:

```
@isTest static void testSearch() {
  User u;

  for (User i : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'user@company.com' LIMIT 1]) {
    u = i;
  }

  System.runAs(u) {
    KN_VacanciesController con = new KN_VacanciesController();

    con.getUAVacancies();
    con.getPostedKNVacancies();

    System.assertEquals(1, uaVacancies.size());
  }
}
```

In the test record I'm inserting, I'm making sure that `ts2__Status__c = 'Open'` and set the `Development_Owner__c` to the user created in the test class.

Any reason why this is returning 0 when it should return 1?

**Edit**
I changed the method as follows:

```
@isTest static void testSearch() {
  User u;

  for (User i : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'user@company.com' LIMIT 1]) {
    u = i;
  }

  ts2__Job__c j = new ts2__Job__c(
    Name = 'Test Job',
    ts2__Status__c = 'Open',
    Development_Owner__c = u.Id
  );

  INSERT j;

  System.runAs(u) {
    KN_VacanciesController con = new KN_VacanciesController();

    con.getUAVacancies();
    con.getPostedKNVacancies();

    System.assertEquals(1, con.uaVacancies.size());
  }
}
```

And the test passed. What I don't understand is I created the exact same `test__Job__c` object in `@testSetup static void testData()` method. I checked the Sharing Settings of the object and they're `Public Read/Write` and the Controller itself is `public with sharing class`. I'm curious to know how come my test method can't access data in the `@testSetup`?

Comment: where are you inserting the records?

Comment: @TusharSharma I've got a `@testSetup static void testData() {}` method.

Comment: What is the sharing model for the ts2__Job__c? Is your controller with or without sharing? You're inserting it with the system user in your `@testSetup` and trying to read it with user `u`. If the OWD are set to private, `u` won't be able to see that record.

Comment: i think you should do this `System.assertEquals(1, con.uaVacancies.size());`

Comment: @TusharSharma I created the `ts2__Job__c` record in the `testSearch()` method and it passed. The controller itself is `public with sharing class` and the OWD for that object is `Public Read/Write`? Also yeah sorry I missed the con. off I didn't copy it straight from the code!

Comment: Perhaps `con.getPostedKNVacancies();` is clearing your list? If you can post the whole code it would be helpful :)

Comment: @mkorman Literally that is all the code in that getPostedKNVacancies() method! It's literally that simple! :)

Comment: I would go back to basics and start with a small test that just inserts your job instance in the `@testSetup` and asserts it exists in a single test. That's the way to find whether `@testSetup` is working for you. Then gradually add other bits and pieces. Maybe your test is exposing a side effect in your controller? Or, perhaps, just assert that the job is there (you're currently not asserting on the existence of the job in the DB, but on what is returned by your controller). I'm sure you can put the code together, but if you want help I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a ts2__Job__c record *in your test class*.

```
@isTest static void testSearch() {
    User u;

    for (User i : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'user@company.com' LIMIT 1]) {
         u = i;
    }

    System.runAs(u) {

        ts2__Job__c tj = new ts2__Job__c ();
        tj.ts2__Status__c = 'Open';
        tj.value__c = 'value';
        tj.value__c = 'value';
        tj.value__c = 'value';

        insert(tj);

        Test.startTest();  
            KN_VacanciesController con = new KN_VacanciesController();
            con.getUAVacancies();
            con.getPostedKNVacancies();
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(1, uaVacancies.size());
    }
}
```

Toufik

Comment: He said he was inserting them in a `@testSetup` method...

Comment: @mkorman Technically, this worked. When I created the record in the `@isTest` method, the assertion worked. However, when I put it in the `@testSetup` it doesn't. Strange and I'm not sure why!